# cannot convert parameter 1 from QDateTime to 'tTimeMods'

Tags: c++, qt, struct, qdatetime

I have a struct tTimeMods which contains QDateTime variables. I have a function which returns this struct. I get one compilation error as mentioned in the title, at the foll line inside compareTimeMods(tTimeMods timeTypeFunction):-

```
QString pathString = appendWithImageName(timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod1);
```

Can you please advise me how to solve this? Here's my code:-

mainwindow.h

```
#define UPDATED_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH "E:\\QT1\\timeStampWithDateModified\\timeStampWithDateModified\\updatedRefImg.jpg"
#define SLEEP_TIME 2000
typedef struct
{
     QDateTime dateTimeMod1;
     QDateTime dateTimeMod2;
}tTimeMods;
tTimeMods timeTypeFunction, timeTypeMain;
tTimeMods findTimeModified();                           //returns a struct
void compareTimeMods(tTimeMods timeTypeFunction);       //takes struct as parameter
QString appendWithImageName(tTimeMods timeTypeFunction);//takes struct as parameter
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
tTimeMods findTimeModified()
{
    QString myFileName = UPDATED_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH;
    QFileInfo info(myFileName);

    /*find last date modified*/
    //QDateTime dateTimeMod1, dateTimeMod2;
    timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod1 = info.lastModified();
    timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod2 = info.lastModified();

    /*find last time modified*/
    //QDateTime timeMod1, timeMod2;
//    timeTypeFunction.timeMod1 = (timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod1).time();
//    timeTypeFunction.timeMod2 = timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod2.time();

    /*return the time part of date time*/
    qDebug()<< "dateTimeMod1: " << timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod1.toString() << endl << "dateTimeMod2: "<< timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod2.toString();
//    qDebug()<< "timeMod1: " << timeTypeFunction.timeMod1.toString() << endl << "timeMod2: "<< timeTypeFunction.timeMod2.toString();
    return(timeTypeFunction);
}    

void compareTimeMods(tTimeMods timeTypeFunction)
    {
        //if(timeMod2 > timeTypeFunction)
        if(timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod2 > timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod1)
        {
            timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod1 = timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod2;
            QString pathString = appendWithImageName(timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod1);
            shiftToRepository(pathString);
        }
    }

    QString appendWithImageName(tTimeMods timeTypeFunction)
    {
       /*appending just the timeMod with the path & image name*/
       QString path = QString("E:\\QT1\\timeStampWithDateModified\\timeStampWithDateModified\\backUp\\updatedRefImg[%1].jpg").arg(timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod1.toString());
       return path;
       //qDebug()<< "path: " << path;
    }

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        //QDateTime timeModified = findDateModified();    //CHECK->this shud give two QDateTime variables to compateTimeMods
        timeTypeMain = findTimeModified();
        while(1)
        {
            Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            compareTimeMods(timeTypeMain);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `appendWithImageName()` function requires a variable of type `tTimeMods` (such as `timeTypeFunction`).

You are instead passing in a variable `timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod1` which is of type `QDateTime`, hence the error.

It *looks* like your intended call should be changed from:

```
QString pathString = appendWithImageName(timeTypeFunction.dateTimeMod1);
```

to:

```
QString pathString = appendWithImageName(timeTypeFunction);
```

since that `appendWithImageName()` function *itself* extracts the information from the `dateTimeMod1` member of the structure passed to it.